# UITabBarController is empty when running the application

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to build an application that has a uiviewcontroller with 3 viewcontrollers attached. I've got the storyboard hooks in place for the 3 view controllers. When this tab bar controller loads up, the ViewControllers array is empty and no tabs actually load up.

I've been able to rearrange some of the tabs in storyboard, which results in 2 out of the 3 tabs showing up, sometimes it's only 1.

It's driving me a little nuts. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image of your storyboard somewhere?

Comment: Did you set in the storyboard the UITabBarController as your initial view controller?

Comment: It's not the initial view. I click a button in another view and it loads up the UITabBarController. I have breakpoints set within tab bar to confirm it's loading. Sometimes the ViewControllers array has 0 items in it, sometimes 1-2 items.